# SemiDefinite representable set that is not Conic Quadratic representable.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming, convex-cone

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

We say that $X$ is Conic Quadratic representable (CQr for short) if
$$X=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists u, A_j\begin{pmatrix}x \\ u\end{pmatrix}-b_j \in L^{m_j}, \ j=1,\dots, N \right\},$$
where $L^m=\left\{(y_1, \dots, y_{m-1}, y_m) \in\mathbb{R}^m: y_m\geq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}y_i^2}\right\}$ is the Lorentz cone.

We say that $X$ is SemiDefinite representable (SDr for short) if there is an affine mapping $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathcal{S}^m$ such that
$$X=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists u \in \mathbb{R}^p, \mathcal{A}(x,u) -B  \text{ is positive semidefinite}\right\},$$
where $\mathcal{S}^m(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $m\times m$ symmetric real matrices.

I know how to prove that every CQr set is also SDr. But what is an example of a SDr set that is not CQr?

Edit: It was told to me that the collection $\mathcal{S}^m_+(\mathbb{R})$ of $m\times m$ positive semidefinite symmetric real matrices isn't CQr. But it seems hard to prove that. It is clear that it is SDr.

Comment: I could be misremembering, but CQr sets can only handle quadratic constraints, right? So any other PSD-representable constraint (e.g. a quartic constraint) may not be captured by CQr? Unless there is some trick?

Comment: @Zim I think this is the right intuition, but it is not clear to me why there can't be any "tricks".

Comment: That seems to have been an open question up until recently https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10107-018-1233-0

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek That is quite surprising! Thanks a lot!